# How to dynamically mount vue component with props

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

**Scenario / context**

I have an overview component which contains a table and an add button. The add button opens a modal component. When i fill in some text fields in the modal and click the save button, a callback (given as prop) is called so the parent component (the overview) is updated. The save button also triggers the model toggle function so the model closes.

So far works everything like expected but when i want to add a second entry, the modal is "pre-filled" with the data of the recently added item.

Its clear to me that this happens because the model component keeps mounted in the background (so its just hidden). I could solve this by "reset" the modals data when the toggle function is triggered but i think there should be a better way.

I have a similar issue when i want to fetch data in a modal. Currently i call the fetch function in the mounted hook of the modal. So in this case the fetch happens when the parent component mounts the modal. This does not make sense as it should only (and each time) fetch when the modal is opened.

I think the nicest way to solve this is to mount the modal component dynamically when i click the "add" (open modal) button but i can't find how i can achieve this. This also avoids that a lot of components are mounted in the background which are possibly not used.

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Example code**

Overview:

```
<template>
  <div>
    // mount of my modal component
    <example-modal
        :toggleConstant = modalToggleUuid
        :submitHandler = submitHandler />
    // The overview component HTML is here
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
                modalToggleUuid: someUuid,
                someList: [],
            }
    },

    mounted() {

    },

    methods: {
          showModal: function() {
        EventBus.$emit(this.modalToggleUuid);
      },

            submitHandler: function(item) {
                this.someList.push(item);
            }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Modal:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="item.type">
    <input v-model="item.name">
    <input v-model="item.location">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
                modalToggleUuid: someUuid,
                item: {},
            }
    },

    mounted() {
            // in some cases i fetch something here. The data should be fetched each time the modal is opened 
    },

    methods: {
          showModal: function() {
        EventBus.$emit(this.modalToggleUuid);
      },

            submitHandler: function(item) {
                this.someList.push(item);
            }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Question**

What is the best practive to deal with the above described scenario?

- Should i mount the modal component dynamically?
- Do i mount the component correctly and should i reset the content all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way and in order to achieve what you want, you can approach this issue with `v-if` solution like this - then `mounted()` hook will run every time when you toggle modal and it also will not be present in DOM when you are not using it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    // mount of my modal component
    <example-modal
      v-if="isShowModal"
      :toggleConstant="modalToggleUuid"
      :submitHandler="submitHandler"
    />
    // The overview component HTML is here
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isShowModal: false,
      modalToggleUuid: someUuid,
      someList: []
    };
  },

  mounted() {},

  methods: {
    showModal: function() {
      this.isShowModal = true;
    },

    submitHandler: function(item) {
      this.someList.push(item);
      this.isShowModal = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Nice way to achieve what i want!, is it the "Vue way" or just a work arround? Is it also recommended/best practice to ALWAYS load ONLY components in the DOM when they are needed ? E.g. for performance or resource usage? Or is this only recommended to achieve some specific requirements like in my case?

Comment: Currently i toggle my modal with an event `e.$emit(theModalId`, args) and e.$on(theModalId, (args) => {do something}). When i use your v-if suggestion, i can show the modal on component mount by default but than i miss the args functionality which i need in some cases (e.g. edit modal). It feels ugly to load the modal component with the v-if AND fire an event to show it, Is there a nicer way to do this? I could set a variable first, than load the component with the var as prop to avoid the event but that feels a bit hacky....

Comment: It is always good to have stuff only when needed, and the rule of thumb in Vue is like this: if it is heavy to initialize - use v-show, if it is relatively easy - go with v-if. And this is definitely best practice and not a workaround.   
Regarding passing props - the good way to do it is not pass in the event, but to pass them as props, for example `<modal v-if="isShowModal" :entity="entityToEdit" />`.

Comment: Thanks for the answeres and clear responses! I don't get the entity part as i already need to define the props before i toggle the component with the v-if. Does it mean that i need to define a placeholder variable (and give it as prop) - fill it with the `entityToEdit` when the edit button is clicked and than toggle the if?

Comment: Yes, there are different possible ways to achieve this - including the one with the event (there is a listener that wraps modal and passes entity there), but they are all at the end will do the same - show up modal and pass there editable stuff, because this is how it works in Vue.  
Different approach to this would be to store the editable entity in Vuex, but the props approach looks clearer to me.

Comment: I run into a new issue when i use your solution. When i disable the modal (by toggle the `v-if` in the parent), the modal disapears but the backdrop div is still there. Because of this i cant click on the add button again.... I tried to use the `beforeDestroy()` hook to hide the modal `$("#" + this._uid).modal("hide");` but that does not work. Can you help me with this as well else i will create a new question.

Comment: Just move v-if on the outermost element that you want to hide `div` in that case and you should be okay.