# Why keeps the "modal-backdrop fade show" exist when the concerning component is un-mounted and how should i "remove/disable" this div

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, modal-dialog

**Situation**

I have a vue component which contains a child component that should show a modal. 
When i toggle the `isShowModal` bool (via button or Vue devtools) the modal is shown. When i click the close button in the modal (or toggle the `isShowModal` in devtools),
the modal is closed. So this works like expected so far.

When i try to open the modal again by clicking on the button to open the modal, it doesn't work. I noticed that the `modal-backdrop` is still "exists" (as an invisible overlay). 
I don't understand why this happens as the `modal-component` is unmounted.

When i close the modal via devtools console with the command `$("#"+ idHere).modal("hide");` the modal, including the backdrop is hided.

Note: i have some reasons why i want to mount/unmount the component to show/close the modal. For this reason is it not an option to fire evens to call the `$("#" + "idHere").modal("show/hide");`
I tried the same with events, just for test purposes and than the modal incl. backdrop was hided perfectly.

The code bellow is not the real code as it contains more logic than required for this question. The example code fits my code very well when it comes the parent/model toggle functionality.
The template of the modal component is almost completely copied from my code.

**Questions**

- How can i close/remove/disable (whatever the correct term is) the backdrop when i unmount my modal component.
- Is the approach i use to mount/unmount components the way to go?
- Is it best practice to toggle modals like i do in Vue ?

**Example code**

Parent component example:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <modal-component
        title = "Zone"
        v-if = "isShowModal"
                :closeCallback = "() => { isShowModal = false }" />

        // Some button that toggles the isShowModal bool 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {

    },
    data() {
      return {
        isShowModal: false,
      }
    },
      showZoneNewModal: function(zone) {
            this.isShowModal = true;
        },
    }
</script>
```

Modal component example:

```
<template>
  <div class="modal fade in" :id="this._uid" style="display: none; padding-right: 17px;" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" v-on:click="closeCallback()" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                  </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            // some header content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          // some body content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      closeCallback: { type: Function, required: true },
        }
    mounted() {
      $("#" + this._uid).modal('show');
    },
        beforeDestroy() {
      $("#" + this._uid).modal("hide");
    },
    }
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE**

This line "spawns" the backdrop div. When i remove all other code from the template of the modal-component the issue is still there.

```
<template>
  <div class="modal fade in" :id="this._uid" style="display: none; padding-right: 17px;" data-backdrop="static">
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I noticed that, for some reason 2 divs are spawned when the `modal-component` is mounted. no 1 looks like this in dev-tools:

```
<div id="9" data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade in box-info show" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;" aria-modal="true"></div>
```

no 2 looks like this in dev-tools. This is also the one that stays "active/alive". I cant find a div with `modal-backdrop` class in one of my 2 components. (also cant find anything with grep).

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason the `:id="this._uid"` was the cause of this issue... Even when i don't understand what exactly happens (lack of knowledge about Vue i gues). - Remove `:id="this._uid"` solves my problem. The id of the modal is still the `_uid` by default.

Answer (score 0):

As I responded in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60786987/how-to-dynamically-mount-vue-component-with-props/60787125?noredirect=1#comment107553379_60787125) - put `v-if` on `div` wrapper and you will be fine (probably).

As any other HTML tag in `<template>`, this backdrop `div` is a part of component and will be removed when component removed.

Also, do not use #id, Vue doesn't need this and there is no reason to do so, if you want to target specific element, you can use `$ref`.

And last one - prefer not to use anonymous functions in templates, since Vue will reallocate memory for it every time, that template is rendered. You can always use method instead.

Comment: I saw your answer but i cannot get it done, for that reason this new question.. I also tried to wrap the `<modal-component .../>` inside a `div` and apply the `v-if` to the div instead of the `modal-component` tag but does also not work. Do you mean that i should set the if on the child component outer div ? `<template> <div v-if="...".>...` ?
As the modal is inside the `modal-component` and that component is unmounted my logic says that it should also cleanup the `modal-backdrop` div.

Comment: You should put your `v-if` to contain this div, `modal-backdrop` you are talking about. Are you using some library for modal?

Comment: The modal-backdrop div is part of the `modal-component` template as you can see in my example. As the whole component is un-mounted i expected that it also unmounts that div. I use Admin LTE template in an Laravel project. Admin LTE also includes bootstrap. 
Thanks for your help and sorry for my 'stupid" questions. I'm not very experienced in Vue/JS

Comment: If this is part of component it is definetely shouldn't exists after v-if is false...

Comment: I'm sure that the modal div is part of the component that is toggled with the v-if statement because that component is the only one that makes use of that bool. I can also reproduce the bug by toggle the bool via the dev tools.

Comment: I signed up to codepen yesterday but cant get the code working at all in codepen... What i noticed in devtools is that 2 divs are spawned when the `modal-component` is mounted. Only one of the 2 divs is unmounted when the `modal-component` is unmounted, the other one stays alive. When i grep my code, i can only find 1 "modal div" - See my question update

Comment: Look at other code / packages / Admin LTE stuff that interacts with it. Also, don't use modal.show / hide methods, use only Vue capabilities, so you can control it

Comment: It took some time and experimenting but finally i got it working now (see comment on my question) - i don't use #id anymore - I dont use events anymore - I understand that i should avoid inline functions in the `<template>` tag but creating a function in the `methods: {}` looks a bit overkill to just toggle a bool. It the disadvantage of using inline functions for such cases that big? Does Vue not release the memory when the component is unmounted - i "unmount" (v-if = false) them when the modal is closed

Comment: It's great that you solved this, it is not overkill, but normal practice. And although memory consumption is not that big, why to do even that if you have a better way :)